# C programming, calling a function

Tags: c

I am new to C and i am trying to iteratively call line in stream and check to see if it contains my search string or if it is null. I cant figure out how to make this check, i get a warning saying  [Warning] comparison between pointer and integer or [Warning] assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast whenever i try and do this. can anyone help?   thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    FILE *fpntr;
    char *file_pathname, *first_line;

      if (argc != 2) {
         fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s FILE\n", argv[0]);
         return EXIT_FAILURE;
      }
   file_pathname = argv[1];

   if ((fpntr = fopen(file_pathname, "r")) == NULL ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening file %s: %s\n", file_pathname, strerror(errno));
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
    } else {
       grep_stream();
       fclose(fpntr);
    }
     return EXIT_SUCCESS;
     }

 int grep_stream(FILE *fpntr, char *string, char *file_pathname) {
          //warning is on next line
     while ((? = get_next_line(fpntr)) == NULL ) {
         perror("Error reading line");
         exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
elseif()
{
    printf("First line in : %s \n %s", file_pathname, string);
}

}

    char *get_next_line(FILE *fpntr) {
   char *buff = malloc(101);
   int pos = 0;
   int next;

   while ((next = fgetc(fpntr)) != '\n' && next != EOF) {

    buff[pos++] = next;

    }
    buff[pos] = '\0';
     if (buff != NULL ) {
    return buff;
     } else
      return NULL ;

          }
```

Comment: first up, pls fix formatting

Comment: Please provide: a code sample that compiles and runs (or is supposed to), and the line numbers where you're getting errors/warnings.

Comment: Second, quote the EXACT message, and identify the EXACT line that's being flagged.

Comment: And after providing detailed description of your problem, try to identify relevant tags as well :)

Comment: Please post compiling code...`elseif()` simply doesn't work, whether it is a function call or a misspelled `else if`.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that C code is compiled top-to-bottom. The function `get_next_line` isn't declared by the time the `while` line is read.

Either move `get_next_line`'s definition to before `main`'s, or forward-declare it by saying:

```
char *get_next_line(FILE *fpntr);
```

beforehand. The reason that you're getting a warning instead of an error is that undeclared functions are assumed to return `int` and no assumptions are made about their parameters. That is, they have the type `int()`.

Also, properly format your code for both your sake and of those who will be answering your questions (or working with you.)

Answer (score 0):

add a * to the pointer of integer to convert it from pointer to integer

Comment: What pointer? I don't see any pointer to integer in OP's code.

Answer (score 0):

> ... i am trying to iteratively call line in stream...

Why not use `fgets()`?

Secondly, to match a substring in a string, you can use `strstr()`

Please use standard C library instead of re-inventing the wheel. It saves the day usually.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <assert.h> // I'm too dumb to program without assertions!
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//#include <unistd.h>  I prefer stdlib.h, couldn't see any need for non-portable header...

#define MAX_LINE    (101)       // define funky constants in one place for easy changing later.

// declare functions before using them
void grep_stream(FILE *fpntr, char *file_pathname);
char *get_next_line(FILE *fpntr);


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    FILE *fpntr;
    char *file_pathname;

    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s FILE\n", argv[0]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    file_pathname = argv[1];

    if ((fpntr = fopen(file_pathname, "r")) == NULL ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening file %s: %s\n", file_pathname, strerror(errno));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    else {
        grep_stream(fpntr, file_pathname);
        fclose(fpntr);
        }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }

void grep_stream(FILE *fpntr, char *file_pathname) {
    char*   line;
    int     got_first = 0;

    assert(fpntr);
    assert(file_pathname);  // I worry the guy who wrote main() might be an idiot like me!

    //warning is on next line [not anymore!]
    while ((line = get_next_line(fpntr)) != NULL ) {
        if(!got_first) {
            printf("First line in : %s \n%s\n", file_pathname, line);
            got_first = 1;
            }
        // if we're not going to use it, let's not leak memory
        free(line);
        }
    }


char *get_next_line(FILE *fpntr) {
    char *buff = malloc(MAX_LINE);
    int pos = 0;
    int next;

    assert(buff != NULL);   // wouldn't it be nice to know malloc() worked?
    while ((next = fgetc(fpntr)) != '\n' && next != EOF) {
        buff[pos++] = (char)next;
        assert(pos < (MAX_LINE-1)); // don't want to be right back on SO with a seg fault, eh?
        }
    buff[pos] = '\0';

    if(next == EOF) {
        free(buff);
        buff = NULL;
        }

    return buff;
    }
```